# Son of a snake or illegitimate son of a snake?

Tags: greek, matthew, luke

In a [lecture before the Biblical Archeology Society](https://store.bib-arch.org/prodinfo.asp?number=9HB37) and on page 123 of [Social-science Commentary on the Gospel of John](https://books.google.com/books?id=Soi3potQSR8C&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=snake-bastards&source=bl&ots=IXB09TIs1p&sig=S9kLZ4MWxS18JWHOJcIm2f-p4Ds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8u5Oqw4HKAhUBOiYKHRpeDXAQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=snake-bastards&f=false) Dr. Richard L. Rohrbaugh (and Dr. [Bruce J. Malina](https://books.google.com/books?id=Soi3potQSR8C&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=snake-bastards&source=bl&ots=IXB09TIs1p&sig=S9kLZ4MWxS18JWHOJcIm2f-p4Ds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8u5Oqw4HKAhUBOiYKHRpeDXAQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=snake-bastards&f=false)) make the claim that verses like Matthew 3:7, 12:34, 23:33 and Luke 3:7, this can best be understood as referring to "snake bastards" or "illegitimate sons of snakes".

In the [Wikipedia page for Matthew 3:7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_3:7), they suggest that

> the use of the word "offspring" implies a child not from a legitimate union.

Citing the [Social-science Commentary](https://books.google.com/books?id=xxOGViLco-UC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Social-Science+Commentary+on+the+Synoptic+Gospels&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj95JLFy4HKAhWJQSYKHV6aC8sQ6AEIHTAA#v=snippet&q=snake%20bastards&f=false) on the [Synoptic Gospels](https://books.google.com/books?id=vuLYAAAAMAAJ&dq=Social-Science+Commentary+on+the+Synoptic+Gospels&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=snake+bastards)

Is there any support for this claim?

Answer (score 10):

"Is there any support for this claim?" It seems unlikely.

**On the one hand**, so far as I can tell, Malina and Rohrbaugh offer no evidence in support of [their assertion](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9kA031YGBDoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q=snake%20bastards&f=false) that the phrase γεννήματα ἐχιδνῶν = *gennēmata echidnōn* -- traditionally, "brood of vipers" -- means "snake bastards".

And, **on the other hand**, I cannot see that this suggestion has made the slightest impact on specialist studies which might be expected to know and interact with it. (Malina and Rohrbaugh are well known and well respected scholars in the "guild".) For example...

1. W. D. Davies, ‎Dale C. Allison, Jr., *[A Critical and Exegetical Commentary on the Gospel According to Saint Matthew, Volume 1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z79ltm3TFWwC&lpg=PP4&dq=editions%3AUXt3ZJeRj1MC&pg=PA304#v=onepage&q&f=false)* (T & T Clark, 1988), p. 304.

   Davies and Allison base their understanding on the contextual contrast with the "children of Abraham", and the other use of *echidna* in the New Testament, Acts 28:3, where the viper runs out of the fire: an "evil ... repugnant ... destructive ... poisonous" creature, and having this nature from birth (thus *gennēmata*). True, they wrote this volume a few years *before* of the work of Malina and Rohrbaugh on the Synoptic Gospels appeared. But they did not revise it in the [2007 abridgement](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DgnUAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=davies%20allison%20matthew&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=vipers&f=false).
2. Craig S. Keener, "[‘Brood of Vipers’ (Matthew 3.7; 12.34; 23.33)](http://jnt.sagepub.com/content/28/1/3.short)", *Journal for the Study of the New Testament* 28.1 (2005): 3-11.

   Keener (who "casts his net widely") attempts to unpack this precise language *via* the classical authors of the Mediterranean world. He argues that the phrase has its meaning in the "parent-murdering" character of the viper in his sources. He thus perceives a deep irony in the Pharisees' claim of honorable descent. Keener makes no mention that I can see of the suggestion of Malina & Rohrbaugh.
3. Michael P. Knowles, "[Serpents, Scribes, and Pharisees](http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/journal_of_biblical_literature/v133/133.1.knowles.html)", *Journal of Biblical Literature* 133.1 (2014): 165–178.

   Finally, and most recently, Michael Knowles assesses Keener's suggestion in the light (in particular) of the Dead Sea Scrolls, and argues rather that "for Matthew, progenitors and progeny are variations on a single theme and that (as in the polemic of the Dead Sea Scrolls) the evangelist has in view venomous serpents in general, rather than any particular species of snake" (p. 169). Once again, there is no reference to Malina & Rohrbaugh.

I can only **conclude** that *had* there been positive evidence in support of Malina & Rohrbaugh's assertion (is it ever anything more than that?), it would have had greater traction in the specialist literature. As it is, this phrase has been considered in quite different terms from that suggested in Malina & Rohrbaugh's pioneering study.

Answer (score 1):

Wisdom of Solomon 4;2-4 seem to suggest so that brood of vipers is offspring of illegitimacy

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: Are you able to expand this answer - it is tantalizingly brief and explains little.